# Save form control values to use later

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome, user-controls, angular-material

I am working on a large form using Angular 5 and Material 2, and to test it, I am using Chrome. It has more than a hundred of controls, some of them are **input of type text**, and others are **select**.

So I want an easy way to **save the selected values** of all of the controls to use later. It's a waste of time filling manually the controls several times.

I found some Chrome extensions to do it, but none of them save the values of the select controls.

Comment: You can use JS in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already using Angular why do you need a chrome extension? just create a dummy object and init it when you getting the form... That way you already have all the fields automatically filled with your dummy values. It is the most easy way.